# Custom location rules for custom post type in ACF

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I've downloaded the ACF plugin for Wordpress and I am trying to add a custom location rule.

What I am trying to do is to get it to detect the categories used in a custom post-type.  For this example, I have installed the WP-Knowledgebase plugin which uses a custom post type for the knowledgebase.

Does anyone know how I can get ACF to use the categories from this in my rules?

Comment: Are you setting up the options for that post type? Have you looked at using the taxonomy option? http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/taxonomy/

Comment: I've installed WP-Knowledgebase and that looks like it uses a custom post type.  In the location rules in ACF, it only detects Wordpress standard categories, not the WP-Knowlegebase categories.  I'm trying to figure out how to get ACF to detect the WP-Knowledgebase categories

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this help you.

To use in `category.php`

```
<?php 
$cover = the_field('cover', 'category_'.get_queried_object_id().''); 
// 'cover' is the name of custom field, replace this with yours.
echo $cover; 
?>
```